# Can I switch monitor inputs with a hotkey?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I currently have a setup where I am using three screens across two dual-monitor, Windows 7 machines. One of the monitors (ViewSonic VG2030WM) is shared across both machines via dual inputs. I use Synergy to share a keyboard and mouse between the machines, but I have to manually switch the monitor when I toggle between machines.

Are there any utilities/tools to switch the inputs on the shared monitor?

I have not had any luck finding any such thing.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the monitor, but that's usually a hardware toggle.  Unless it's built with some sort of software controls that would let you do that, the only way would be some kind of KVM (and since you're using Synergy I assume that's less than ideal)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but there is this VESA standard MCCS and there is this command 60h. Google around it :)

Comment: Related: [How do I switch the input for my monitor from DVI to HDMI from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/862985/how-do-i-switch-the-input-for-my-monitor-from-dvi-to-hdmi-from-my-pc)

Comment: I have been doing something like this with Synergy + AutoHotKey: https://moshen.net/posts/virtual_kvm/

Answer (score 5):

Just a quick thought, you may be able to utilize the presentation mode toggle.

press windows key + P  and switch to either "projector only" or "computer only" and maybe the monitor will then pick up the remaining active video feed from the other computer.

I don't really have a way to test this but its worth a shot!

Comment: 4 upvotes so far.  Can anyone confirm if this approach works?

Answer (score 2):

[mControl](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/) seems to do this (if you're still looking for it), I'm evaluating it at the moment for the same thing and seems to work.

Comment: mControl doesn't seem to exist anymore on the website.

Comment: It is not, but the link [on forum](http://forums.entechtaiwan.com/index.php?topic=6725.0) is still available

Answer (score 0):

There are KVM switches available with software controlled switching, but your best bet would probably just be to use RemoteDesktop, assuming they are both PCs